# How to create custom enum like this on right top section in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-editor

I have a question about how to create a custom enum that looks like one of the ones used in the top right section of the Unity editor (visible in the picture)?

I want to add one custom enum to the right site of ,,Layers'' enum button presented on the screen.

Specifically, I'm looking for a reference to the documentation or the name of an element that should be overwritten/used when building your own editor element :)

[image: Pictore from Unity editor]

Comment: check unity's [Editor class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) to enhance your components with extra cool UI features

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I'm interested in this section "Toolbar" how to add enum to there, where are "Layers" and "Layout" enums presented. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use ready to use library [Unity Toolbar Extender](https://github.com/marijnz/unity-toolbar-extender) for that. You can easily extend unity's built-in toolbar from script.

> This example code is shown in action in the gif below. Just hook up
> your GUI method to ToolbarExtender.LeftToolbarGUI or
> ToolbarExtender.RightToolbarGUI to draw left and right from the play
> buttons.

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class SceneSwitchLeftButton
{
    static SceneSwitchLeftButton()
    {
        ToolbarExtender.LeftToolbarGUI.Add(OnToolbarGUI);
    }

    static void OnToolbarGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

        if(GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("1", "Start Scene 1"), ToolbarStyles.commandButtonStyle))
        {
            SceneHelper.StartScene("Assets/ToolbarExtender/Example/Scenes/Scene1.unity");
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("2", "Start Scene 2"), ToolbarStyles.commandButtonStyle))
        {
            SceneHelper.StartScene("Assets/ToolbarExtender/Example/Scenes/Scene2.unity");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]